# Trying to get ANY effect to work on my shape

Tags: vba, parameters, powerpoint, effect, shapes

```
'declare Variables 
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oeff As Effect

' SET objects
Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
Set oshp = osld.Shapes("Star 1")
Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=oshp, effectid:=msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor)

With oeff
.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = RGB(Red:=10, Green:=45, Blue:=201)
.Timing.Duration = 2
End With

oshp.Left = oshp.Left + 100 ' Added to verify something was coming thru!
```

Sadly it still doesn't work... It compiles, but no effect on the slide...

I've updated the code to show your recommendations

NB: The fill color is defined at the creation of the shape

I added a + 100 to the left value of the shape just to make sure it was actually getting thru, it does move but it won't change color...

Is there an "official" list somewhere of what effects support what parameters?

Thanks for slugging thru this with me! :)

Comment: +1 The `Color1` property does not exist in PowerPoint 2010, yet the example given in the documentation for `Color2` does use `Color1` -- and, as a result, doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your frustration: As mentioned in my comment, the `Color1` property does not exist in PowerPoint 2010, yet the example given in the documentation for `Color2` does use `Color1` -- and, as a result, it doesn't compile!

The correct way is to give the *shape* a color, like this:

```
oshp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Red:=0, Green:=0, Blue:=255)
```

This will be the starting color. The animation effect can then change that color:

```
With oeff
    .EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = RGB(Red:=0, Green:=255, Blue:=255)
    .Timing.Duration = 2
End With
```

Note that `Timing` is a property of `Effect`, not of `EffectParameters` as in the code given in your question.

Comment: I've tried this and updated the code in my original question, it still doesn't work. I finally got a pulse from addEffect by adding a triggerType (Which the documentation says are optional) but it wont respond to the color2 line, it simply turns my shape to a reddish tint regardless of the parameters given in the RGB section

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Still doesn't compile? I just tested my code again and it works just fine, eliminating the error mentioned in your original question. This may be a stupid question, but: Have you tried actually *playing* your slide show? Because the color-change animation will only happen while the slide show is being played; it won't happen in the normal slide view.

Comment: Yes it compiles but without a triggerType nothing happens (They're supposed to be optional no?). With a triggerType the color2 argument is ignored, the shape turns to a red-rust color, regardless of the RGB setup. Yet the timing argument is used... Yes I'm looking at it in slide view mode ;)

Comment: I was fiddling around some more, every time you add an effect to a shape it stacks it on top of the previous time you did it (This can be seen in the animation pane). This probably breeds some kind of conflict if you call the sub that adds the effect a couple times... With oeff.delete you can remove it but you can't do it right after else it looks like the added effect doesn't have time to trigger. Delete / Add on the Shape with the effect also clears that stack of course... after a few times that the effect is called it starts to only go kinda half way thru the effect

Comment: True, every time you call `.AddEffect` it *adds* an effect on top of whatever was there before. This question is now pretty messy with a long comment chain, and you've completely changed the question text. I suggest you ask a new question with a description of this new problem. The answer I gave does solve the problem originally stated in this question -- if starting from a fresh slide with no effects for the shape in question.

Comment: @MarcFavreau, I tested this as well and all is working fine with the `AddEffect`, especially if you use `.AddEffect(Shape:=oshp, effectid:=msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)` you'll be able to see the effect right way. There may be something else happening with your slides. Can you start from a brand new deck, insert a star and run the code again?